# How to extract nested variables in kwrgs?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a function which is supposed to grab a query from a remote server and run it on OsQuery. I have been able to configure it so that the data is sent from the remote server and is received in the kwargs data structure.

When I run `print(kwargs)` it shows a long dict, in it I have a field called `'osquery_query'` which I'd like to extract and print out .

The output looks like this:

```
 'object_type': 4, 'principal': {'display_name': 'XXXX', 'id': 1, 'name': 'XXXX', 'type': 'user'}, 'properties': {**'osquery_query': 'select * from logged_on_users'**}, 'row': None, 'task': None, 'type_info': {'artifact': {'fields': {'relating_incidents': {'id': 121, 'values': {}}, 'summary': {'id': 122, 'values': {}}
```

I have attempted to extract the data using kwargs.get like so:

```
def _osquery_handler_function(self, event, *args, **kwargs):
    query = kwargs.get('osquery_query')
    print("Query Is: %s", query)
```

but that doesn't really catch anything (just shows me that it's empty) how could I extract the data from the dictionary and print it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a value from nested dictionaries or other nested datastructures, you need to index each level separately, like so:

```
def _osquery_handler_function(self, event, *args, **kwargs):
     query = kwargs['properties']['osquery_query']
     print("Query Is: %s", query)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time!

So that doesn't seem to work for me, throws me an error - any chance you could help?

 ERROR:

'properties'
  File "manager.py", line 677, in _dispatcher
    value = event_handler(event, *eargs, **ekwargs)
  File "Test1.py", line 28, in _osquery_handler_function
    query = kwargs['properties']['osquery_query']

Comment: In that case, something is missing from the output of `print(kwargs)`. Are you sure you copied everything into your question? If you could add `from pprint import pp` and then use `pp(kwargs)` to pretty-print the keyword arguments, and then edit your question with the full output you get, I'll be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: Yes! I was missing another level, when I ran pp it was really easy to see that. Thank you so much!